# Laravel Blade Template - How to use incremental variable in foreach loop

Tags: laravel, loops, variables, laravel-blade

I need to know if there is a laravel blade way to do the following without using PHP tags.

```
<?php $i = 1; ?>
@foreach($rows as $row)
   //do something
   <?php $i++; ?>
@endforeach
```

As you can see the code looks ugly with  tags and its time wasting to write extra tags.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58181463/9515071 you shoud try This is work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using laravel > 5.4 then you can use [$loop variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#the-loop-variable) to get the index.

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    @if ($loop->first)
        This is the first iteration.
    @endif

    @if ($loop->last)
        This is the last iteration.
    @endif

    <p>This is user {{ $user->id }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Similarly, you can apply no need to reinvent the wheel.

```
@foreach($rows as $row)
   //do something

 {{ $loop->index }} 
@endforeac
```

hope this helps

Comment: I don't think he needs something with first or last loop.

Comment: @AshutoshSharma this is just an example.

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz you are real champ. Thanks for your answer its working for me, both the solution you have provided.

Comment: @TahirAfridi but you need incremental $i after foreach loop then?

Comment: @JinalSomaiya ```{{ $loop->index }} ``` is available in inside a foreach loop you can explore the docs

Comment: @AdnanMumtaz I know but in question TahirAfridi taken $i variable before foreach loop and increment it with total loop count and if need to use $i after foreach loop then?

Answer (score 6):

use index

```
@foreach($rows as $index=>$row)
  {{$index}}
@endforeach
```

if you want to define some variable then use `@php($counter=0)`

```
 @php($counter=0)
 @foreach($rows as $index=>$row)
      $counter=$counter+2;
      {{$counter}}
 @endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't like the php key, its still in your answer. By the way I accepted the @adnan's answer which is more precise and to the point. I give you 1 upvote

Answer (score 2):

Try this     $loop->iteration

```
 @foreach($rows as $row)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                <td>{{ $row->item1}}</td>
                <td>{{ $row->item2}}</td>
            </tr>
 @endforeach
```

The result will be like this

```
---------------------------------
Si#     |    item 1    |  item2 |
---------------------------------
1       |    AAA       |  111   |
2       |    BBB       |  222   |
---------------------------------
```